# post() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'request'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to save a `post` request but I am getting `post() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'request'` error.

View:

```
class MakeLeaveRequest(generics.CreateAPIView):
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
  serializer_class = MakeLeaveRequestSerializer
# login_url = '../../users/v1/login/'

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        # self.perform_create(serializer)
            date = serializer.save()
            print(date)
        # headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({'ok':'ok'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serializer:

```
class MakeLeaveRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # date_to = serializers.DateField()
    # date_from = serializers.DateField()
    # description = serializers.CharField()
    # types_of_leave = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ('date_to', 'date_from', 'description', 
                 'types_of_leave',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        print(user)   
        # print(validated_data['date_to'])
        try:
            LeaveRequest.objects.create(user = user)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        return user
```

Trace Path :

```
admin
2019-01-02
Internal Server Error: /attend/v1/leaveRequest
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/ 
python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
 response = get_response(request)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/attendanceregistersystem/attendance/views.py", line 78, in create
date = serializer.save()
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/attendanceregistersystem/attendance/serializers.py", line 30, in create
LeaveRequest.objects.create(user = user)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 769, in save_base
update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in send
for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
File "/home/bishwa/attendanceRegisterSystem/attendanceregistersystem/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
```

> TypeError: post() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and
>   'request'

Comment: Where is your exception raising line?

Comment: @JPG sorry , now I have added the expection line

Comment: This isn't what I meant. Please do add the error traceback

Comment: @JPG I have now included it